# append another file path to environment variable

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I need to update client PC's environment variable using Active Directory Group Policy. I have to append new part to at the end of each PC's "Path" variable. is there any way to append new part to "Path" variable without deleting existing "Path" value ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes

`Path=%path%;c:\yournewpath;`